# Advice on handling multidimensional array with Codeigniter or possible other solution?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a list of users and checkboxes, I need to get the id's of each check box:checked as well as a subject field and a message field and pass to my controller. The only way I could think to do this was to grab each id and duplicate the subject and message fields and pass to a multidimensional array to my controller. My array looks like this:

```
[{id: "46", subject: "sample subject1", message: "test message1"}{id: "46", subject: "sample subject1", message: "test message1"}]
```

This seems really redundant as I only need the list of user ids and 1 copy of the message and subject fields in the array but not sure if there is a better way to do this or not. Is it possible to send two different arrays via ajax to my codeigniter controller? If so how do I access them in the controller?

Here is an example of my code to collect ids and create the array. If this is the best method I am still not sure how to handle a multidimensional array in my controller. Normally I would access the array contents using $this->input->post('key') but, that wont work: I think I would need to loop through the array first in the controller but not sure how to do.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.send_btn', function(e) { 

//get ids of selected users
var subject = 'test subject';
var message = 'test message';
var data = [];

$(':checkbox[name="people_checked[]"]:checked').each (function () {
  data.push({
    id: this.id,
    subject: subject,
    message: message
  })
  
});

  $.ajax({
      url: "/message/send_message",
      method: "POST",
      success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success');
        
     }
 })
```

});

Any help advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to DRY up the array, convert it to an object which has the `subject` and `message` properties in the root. Then you can provide the `ids` property as an array. It would look something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.send_btn', function(e) {
  var data = {
    subject: 'test subject',
    message: 'test message',
    ids: $(':checkbox[name="people_checked[]"]:checked').map((i, el) => el.id).get()
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "/message/send_message",
    method: "POST",
    data: data, // note this was added, you didn't send a body in the original
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('Success');
    }
  })
});
```

The output would be:

```
{
  subject: 'test subject',
  message: 'test message',
  ids: [ 123, 987 ]
}
```

You would obviously need to amend your `/message/send_message` endpoint to work with a request body in that format.